# Authorization in graphql resolvers as middleware

Tags: node.js, graphql, decorator, apollo-server

I need to check is user authorized to do this or to do that in resolvers, but i don't want to write same codes in every resolvers. So it seems i should use decorators. But i don't know how to use decorators there without classes.

the decoded UserId from `jwt` token is there i `req` object with using context, and my resolver like this:

```
import { isAllowed } from 'somewhere';
export default {
  Query: {
    async q1(_, args, {req}) {
      if (!isAllowed(req.userId,'action') throw new Error('Not Authorized!');
    },
  ...
}
```

I've something like this in my mind:

````
export default {
  Query: {
    @isAllowed
    async q1(_, args, {req}) {
      // ...
    },

    // this method doesn't need authorization.
    async q2(_,args, {req}) {

    }
}```

But i don't know how to implement it.
````

Answer (score 1):

I found i should use `Schema directives` to handle authorization instead of resolver method decoration.